# Use $_POST to get input values on the same page

Tags: php

Sorry if this is a rather basic question.

I have a page with an HTML form. The code looks like this:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
  Example value: <input name="example" type="text" />
  Example value 2: <input name="example2" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in my file `submit.php`, I have the following:

```
<?php
  $example = $_POST['example'];
  $example2 = $_POST['example2'];
  echo $example . " " . $example2;
?>
```

However, I want to eliminate the use of the external file. I want the $_POST variables on the same page. How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783381/same-page-processing

Comment: @Schleis Sorry, did not see that question.

Comment: If youre just echoing the variable onclick it may be better to just use javascript

Comment: @JohnDoe That was just an example. I'm not just echoing the variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put this on a php file:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $example = $_POST['example'];
    $example2 = $_POST['example2'];
    echo $example . " " . $example2;
  }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  Example value: <input name="example" type="text" />
  Example value 2: <input name="example2" type="text" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

It will execute the whole file as PHP. The first time you open it, `$_POST['submit']` won't be set because the form has not been sent.
Once you click on the submit button, it will print the information.

Comment: An even better solution would be to [leave the action attribute empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401521/is-action-really-required-on-forms) or [leave it out altogether if you're using HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048833/does-html5-require-an-action-attribute-for-forms).

Comment: @thordarson Thanks for the heads-up! however, I've always preferred to put it just to be explicit. I think $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] would've been better for this example.